# How to initialize and load data when moving to a screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to populate my lists by making API calls when moving to a screen in `flutter`. I tried calling the async function in the init state however it takes time to load the data of course, and that leads to a null error.

I tried using a future builder in my view. However, I want to make multiple API calls and I don't think that is possible with one future builder. And I would like to avoid having different future builders for each list.
Is there a neat way to do this?

Also is it advisable to load data and pass it on from the previous screen.. since I would like to avoid the loading time?

[image]

current code

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: getAllData,
          initialData: [],
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.isEmpty) return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),));
            else {
              return createNewTaskView(context, snapshot.data);
            }
          }),
```

init method

```
  @override
  void initState() {

    
    this.getAllData = getSocieties();

  }
```

Comment: You can load all the data in the initial screen and then pass it along to the next screen via the constructor.

Comment: Is this a good solution for large amounts of data ?

Comment: I am unaware of what your data looks like. Usually if its list screen -> details screen. If its something like that, it's better to load only the list data in the first screen and then pass the id of the selected item in the constructor of the details screen, and there you can use the id to load the details data

Comment: The solution for this task for me is this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61802303/6327465