# Why is FutureBuilder called multiple times?

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

Excuse the ignorance i am new to Flutter.

I am practicing on a course I did and I have the following scenario:

I have a view where I consume a web service in the method `getDataArray` (`FutureBuilder`), and I just want it to be done only once when this view is accessed.

I also have a `TextField`, `FutureBuilder` and the `TextField` is in the`build()`. My `widget` is a `StatefulWidget` because it needs to be redrawn to show the character counter of my `TextField`, so I think this is the reason that every time I type something the `build` runs and call the `FutureBuilder` again.

How can I solve that?

```
    class Pagina3 extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    Pagina3State createState() {
        return Pagina3State();
    }
    }

    class Pagina3State extends State<Pagina3> {
    String _input = "";

    //returns a web service
    Future getDataArray() async {
        final dynamic resp =
            await web.http_Web(webservices.url["DATOS"], "POST", {}, context);
        return resp;
    }

    Pagina3() {}

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var validators = new Validators();
        var utils = new Utils();
        return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Page 3'),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
            child: Form(
                child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                        counter: Text('Letras ${_input.length.toString()}'),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.alternate_email),
                        hintText: 'ejemplo@correo.com',
                        labelText: 'Correo electrónico',
                        ),
                        validator: (value) => validators
                            .fn_checkValidation([validators.required(value)]),
                        onChanged: (valor) {
                        setState(() {
                            _input = valor;
                        });
                        },
                    ),
                    Container(
                        child: FutureBuilder(
                            future: getDataArray(),
                            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                if (snapshot.data["ok"] == false) {
                                return Text("ha ocurrido un problema");
                                }
                                return (Text("Exito"));
                            } else {
                                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                            }
                            }),
                    )
                    ],
                ),
                ),
            ),
            ),
        ),
        );
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Anything that's within a widget's `build()` method can trigger anytime — this is, you shouldn't rely on anything critical that could have impact on it. For example, opening a keyboard or closing, is enough to trigger multiple calls to `build()` on a widget.

Your `FutureBuilder` is just a widget on your tree, and because of that, anytime it rebuilds (for example, whenever you type on the `TextField`), it will call your `getDataArray()` because it doesn't actually really know if that has already been called or not.

If you just want it to be called *once*, you can assign it to a state member and assign it to your `FutureBuilder`. That will be preserved as long as that state exists on the widget tree.

You can for example assign it on `initState()` if you want to call it only per state lifecycle or at `didChangeDependencies()` for example, if you want to refresh that call anytime a dependency changes.

```
 class Pagina3State extends State<Pagina3> {
  late final Future myFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
     myFuture = getDataArray();
  }

  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       
       child: FutureBuilder(
              future: myFuture,
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: wow What a great response, thank you very much. Friend since you know a lot about this and taking advantage of your great knowledge, can you explain to me in which cases I should use the `didChangeDependencies ()` that you mentioned please? And my last question, can you do something to save the cache of my current view? for example I write a word in my text field, if I navigate back with a `pop` and return to my current page, my text field is reset.

Comment: `didChangeDependencies()` will be called only when for example an InheritedWidget calls all of its children to rebuild (for example, your app likely inherits from `Theme` and `MediaQuery`, so anytime those have changes, they can call `didChangeDependencies`, the same for your own `InheritedWidget`s). To maintain state between screens, you have multiple approaches, InheritedWidgets being one (check Provider package for example), you can handle the `TextEditingController` or, an immediate way or you can even pass arguments between screens directly.

Comment: One last question, is it necessary to use super () inside the init?

Comment: Yes, you should always call  `super` methods on their overrides.

Comment: can you help me with this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61808897/how-to-validate-before-navigating-to-a-route

Comment: getting an error with this solution: The argument type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Object>?'.

Comment: @giorgio79 replace the `Future` with `Future?` which is required if you have null safety support or with a `late final` keyword if you're not going to change it later. I'll update my answer as well.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by [Miguel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61802303/702954), you should assign your future to a variable outside of `build()` scope so it is only run once.

Note that since Dart 2.0 you can use [lazy initialization](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#lazy-initialization) with [late final variables](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-final-variables) to write this in a even shorter way:

```
 class Pagina3State extends State<Pagina3> {
   late final Future myFuture = getDataArray();

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       child: FutureBuilder(
              future: myFuture,
      )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are using setstate in your textfield action and it rebuild everything. I faced with similar problem with one of my apps and used a bool to avoid it, I named it firstRun, if it is true I called my future function in future builder if it's not I made it null like below ode sample. But I am not sure that is best way to do it, also you need to make this bool false in somewhere (in initstate perhaps);

```
bool firstRun = true;

 @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {...
                            ...
                             onChanged: (valor) {
                        firstRun = false;
                        setState(() {
                            _input = valor;
                        });
                        },
                      .....
                     FutureBuilder(
                            future: firtRun ? getDataArray() : null,
                            builder: (...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable which return futureBuilder, so when you call setState only widget go rebuild but variable don't, so you can solve your issue.

```
 Widget futureWidget;

  @override
  void initState() {
    futureWidget = FutureBuilder(
      future: callme(),
      builder: (_, sanpshot) {
        print("future method call");
        if (sanpshot.hasData) {
          return Text(sanpshot.data.toString());
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  callme() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    return "success";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build method call");
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("press"),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {});
            },
          ),
          futureWidget,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        The solution to the problem FutureBuilder called multiple times?
        
        <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
        
        



        
        if you are using bloc Cubit code is here:-

    class FaqsCubit extends Cubit<FaqsStates> {
          FaqsCubit() : super(FaqsStatesInitialStates());
        
          FaqsRequest? faqsRequest;
           bool dataLoaded=false;//set a variable to first time load data from API
          Future<FaqsRequest?> getFaqsData() async {
            try {
              emit(FaqsStatesLoading());
        
              FaqsRepo().getFaqsDataRepo().then((value) {
                if (value == null) {
                  emit(FaqsStatesError());
                } else {
                  faqsRequest = value;
        ///check condition here 
                  if(dataLoaded==false){
                    emit(FaqsStatesLoaded(faqsRequest!));
        ///change value second time api will not call
                    dataLoaded=true;
                  }
        
        
                }
              });
            } catch (e) {
              emit(FaqsStatesError());
            }
        
            return faqsRequest;
          }
        }


///Call future builder like that in your widget:-
FutureBuilder<FaqsRequest?>(
              future: context.read<FaqsCubit>().getFaqsData(),


<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution to the problem is to add a delay to the future builder event.
Connection occurs during standby and initstate is not triggered

```
 _initializeFirebase() async {
    //ADD DURATION
   await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
   return Firebase.initializeApp();
 }
```

Run Future Builder

```
return FutureBuilder(
  // Initialize FlutterFire
  future: _initializeFirebase(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    // Check for errors
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
    // Once complete, show your application
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Chat Application',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          initialRoute: SignScreen.routeName,
          routes: {
            SignScreen.routeName: (content) => SignScreen(),
            ChatScreen.routeName: (content) => ChatScreen(),
            LoginScreen.routeName: (content) => LoginScreen(),
            RegisterScreen.routeName: (content) => RegisterScreen(),
          });
    }

    // Otherwise, show something whilst waiting for initialization to complete
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  },
);
```