# how to make a validation before navigating to a route?

Tags: flutter

I have 2 pages, `page1` and`page2`. I want to validate that when the app is opened and there is no token or it is false, it redirects to `page1` otherwise it redirects to `page2`, and when I have more pages I want that if there is a valid token, continues the normal flow of the navigation, I was trying this and I have this problem:

in the gif the token is not defined, the validation apparently does well, but the problem is that it continues to reload the current view, I am looking for something more optimal that avoids loading a route if some condition is not met

[image]

how can I solve that?

```
Map<String, WidgetBuilder> getRoutes() {
  return <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    '/': (BuildContext context) =>
      checkNavigation("/", pag1(), context),
    'page1': (BuildContext context) =>
      checkNavigation("page1", page1(), context),
    'page2': (BuildContext context) =>
        checkNavigation("/page2", page2(), context)
  };
}

dynamic checkNavigation(
    String page, dynamic pageContext, BuildContext context) {
  if (storage.token && page == "/") {
    //Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, 'page2', (_) => false);
    return page2();
  } else if (storage.token == false) {
    //Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, 'page1', (_) => false);
    return page1();
  } else {
    return pageContext;
  }
}


 in my main:
  .
  .
  .
      MaterialApp(
      title: 'route validation',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: getRoutes(),
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible code?

Comment: Where is storage.token set up and are you sure it contains the value you expect? Also, in your code snippet you have a reference to pag1() rather than page1() so I assume the code you posted is not actually the code you are running?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to control this behavior in your own abstractions and change routes only if necessary.

I would recommend to add some splash screen at root route and navigate to appropriate route, once token is initialized.

```dart
Future<void> asyncInit() {/*...*/}

void initState() {
  /* ... */
  asyncInit().then((_) => /* push appropriate first route */);
}

Map<String, WidgetBuilder> getRoutes() {
  return <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    '/': (BuildContext context) => SplashScreen(),
    /* other routes */
  };
}
```

If you need intercept other navigation events you can add your own proxy class, this may be easily implemented using [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package

```dart
class MyNavigator {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  MyNavigator(this.navigatorKey);
  static MyNavigator of(BuildContext context) => context.read<MyNavigator>();

  Future<T> pushNamed<T extends Object>(
   BuildContext context,
   String routeName, {
   Object arguments,
  }) {
    // add any additional logic and conditions here
    return navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed<T>(routeName, arguments: arguments);
  }
  // add any other methods you need
}

// somewhere at the top of widget tree above Widgets/Material/CupertinoApp widget.
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

// add provider with navigator key above navigator
Provider(
  create: (_) => MyNavigator(navigatorKey),
  child: MaterialApp(navigatorKey: navigatorKey, /*...*/)
)

// use it
MyNavigator.of(context).pushNamed(...)
```

There is much work going right now to implement Navigator 2.0 with Router and Pages API, which gives you more control and flexibility on routing.

tracking issue:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45938

design docs:

- https://flutter.dev/go/navigator-with-router
- https://flutter.dev/go/router-and-widgetsapp-integration

[Pages API](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html) is already available in current stable release, but there is not enough documentation and examples at the moment.