# Number of items inside ListView increase when resizing

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-futurebuilder

I've added a `FutureBuilder` and inside him I have a `ListView` that is populated by data from `Firebase`. My problem is that when I resize the window of the browser, the number of the items from `ListView` increase.
I've uploaded a [Video](https://streamable.com/bjdlxa) to better understand my issue.

This is my `FutureBuilder` with the `ListView`

```
FetchLocalCouncilData data = Provider.of<FetchLocalCouncilData>(context);
FutureBuilder(
              future: data.getDataFromFirebase(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
                if (snap.hasData) {
                  return SizedBox(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                        LocalCouncilData localData = snap.data[index];
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text('${localData.name}'),
                          trailing: TextButton.icon(
                              onPressed: () async {},
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                              label: const Text('')),
                        );
                      }),
                      itemCount: data.getLength(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            ),
```

I get the data from `Firebase` like this:

```
  getDataFromFirebase() async {
    _instance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    _localModel = [];
    CollectionReference collectionReference = _instance.collection('test');
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await collectionReference.doc('database').get();
    var data = snapshot.data() as Map;
    var localData = data['testArray'] as List<dynamic>;
    for (var element in localData) {
      _localModel.add(LocalCouncilData.fromJson(element));
    }
    return _localModel.reversed.toList();
  }
```

```html
<iframe src="https://streamable.com/e/bjdlxa" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Add your code first !!!!!

Comment: @OMiShah sorry, I forgot to add it

Comment: The video link is not accessible, is it working for you? I can't check it

Comment: It is accessible to me, I'll check it again

Comment: I've embedded the video in the post

Comment: It won't work as it seems the domain is blocked by my internet provider :/ will check using some VPN and let you know.

Comment: Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61802115/why-is-futurebuilder-called-multiple-times