# Flutter FutureBuilder get called twice

Tags: flutter, dart

my FutureBuilder in the `Dashboard` class is called twice. So that the background color of the `ItemContent` is blinking. For now I am using a boolean to prevent the first reloading.

My ItemContent does have an active and inactive state which is reflected by the background color. With a click the state changes. I set the state in the `ItemContent` to have an imediate UI interaction, upload the new value and then refresh the parent. I need to refresh the parent because the new value is influencing another widgets state why I want to call a setstate on the parent so that the FutureBuilder calles the API again.

I also tried to not bind the `widget.value` in the `ItemContent` directly but used a local variable. But then the callback of the `onTap` function in case someone returns to the screen do not trigger the reload.

I am confused and the solution with the bool feels wrong...

```
class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  Dashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Dashboard> createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  void onTap(String groupId, String cw) {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => GroupDetail(
                  groupId: groupId,
                  cw: cw,
                ))).then((value) {
      reload();
    });
  }

  void reload() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: FutureBuilder<MeModel>(
        future: WechieverBackend.getMe(context),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<MeModel> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // READ THE API OBJs
            // Generate ContentList
            List<Widget> itemContentList =
                List.generate(item?.content?.length ?? 0, (index) {
              MeModelAchievementsItemContent? c = item?.content![index];
              return ItemContent(
                  userId: achievement?.userId ?? '',
                  contentId: c?.id ?? '',
                  label: c?.label ?? '',
                  value: c?.value ?? 0,
                  refreshParent: reload);
            });
            // Place ItemContentList into a Gridview etc.
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return ErrorTextWidget();
          } else {
            return LoadingWidget();
          }
        },
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

```
class ItemContent extends StatefulWidget {
  final String userId;
  final String contentId;
  int value;
  final String label;
  Function refreshParent;

  ItemContent(
      {Key? key,
      required this.userId,
      required this.contentId,
      required this.label,
      required this.value,
      required this.refreshParent})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ItemContent> createState() => _ItemContentState();
}

class _ItemContentState extends State<ItemContent> {
  int myValue = 0;
  bool wasUpdated = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myValue = widget.value;
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant ItemContent oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (!wasUpdated) {
      myValue = widget.value;
    } else {
      wasUpdated = false;
    }
  }

  void onTapItem(String userId, String itemContentId, int value) async {
    String jwtUserId = await AuthHelpers.getUserId();
    if (jwtUserId == userId) {
      if (value == 0) {
        value = 1;
      } else {
        value = 0;
      }
      setState(() {
        wasUpdated = true;
        myValue = value;
      });
      bool isSent =
          await WechieverBackend.setItemContent(context, itemContentId, value);
      if (isSent) {
        widget.refreshParent();
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => onTapItem(widget.userId, widget.contentId, myValue),
      child: Card(
          color: Helpers.bgColorDay(context, myValue),
          child: Center(child: Text(Helpers.weekDay(context, widget.label)))),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is FutureBuilder called multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61802115/why-is-futurebuilder-called-multiple-times)

Comment: `WechieverBackend.getMe(context)` will be  called after every build

Comment: Already read this post and it does not answer it.

Actually the `WechieverBackend.getMe(context)` is not called twice. this is the API call

Comment: why don't you initialize your `Future` for example in `initState`?

Comment: I checked it again.

1. the ItemContent refreshs the color
2. then I call setstate on the parent
3. futurebuilder is called with the old data and changes the color again
4. then the API call which is the future of the FutureBuilder is called
5. then the FutureBuilder is again called with the correct data and changes again the color

Comment: @pskink    I am very interested in your thoughts :D... what would this change?

Comment: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html - i mean the section that starts with *"The future must have been obtained earlier, [...]"*

Comment: okay. I did move the Future outside. How do I trigger now a refresh?

if I do something like `void reload() {
    setState(() {
      _futureAPI = WechieverBackend.getMe(context);
    });
  }`

the UI blinks again

Comment: In my opinion there is an issue that I am calling the setState on the child and directly after the backend call on the parent.